Simulation Window not Visible
I am working on a Python program to simulate waste management activities in a residential estate but I cannt see the visulation and the animation. What can I do?
I know there will be solution to my challenge here. So, I expect a solution that will work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
